# host name to ip resolution is not using /etc/hosts file

Tags: dns, ping, redhat-enterprise-linux, telnet, hostname

I have defined some hostnames in /etc/hosts i.e. `192.168.15.20   example.com` when I do `ping example.com` I get the reolved ip as the one defined in /etc/hosts but when I change this IP to another IP (keeping the same host name) it still reads the old IP. also sometimes when I do ping it uses the new IP but when doing telnet I see the old IP in the log of the command.
I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: I made a few changes to hosts on mine and they are instant. But it might be worth trying to restart the network adapters on the server with `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`

Comment: Have you checked your nsswitch.conf file? I'm not too familiar with the details, but I know that it CAN be setup to skip the hosts file, if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Address lookups done via standard glibc functions may be cached using *nscd* (which is a standard part of glibc, although very rarely enabled by default).

If the nscd service is running, tell it to invalidate the caches:

```
nscd -i hosts
```

(It is not always enough to just restart the service, as it might store the cache on disk. On the other hand, a service restart might be required to reload *nsswitch.conf* changes.)